# Nullpointer exception while changing text in onCreate()

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I get a nullpointer exception here is the code where its laying.

```
    final TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
final Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            view.setText("These questions will help me to help you :)");
        }
    });
```

This is my log file:

```
24 15:21:45.441: E/AndroidRuntime(376): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.icemountaininc.app/com.icemountaininc.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-24 15:21:45.441: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1660)
11-24 15:21:45.441: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1752)
11-24 15:21:45.441: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
11-24 15:21:45.441: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:993)
11-24 15:21:45.441: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-24 15:21:45.441: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
11-24 15:21:45.441: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3997)
11-24 15:21:45.441: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-24 15:21:45.441: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
11-24 15:21:45.441: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
11-24 15:21:45.441: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
11-24 15:21:45.441: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-24 15:21:45.441: E/AndroidRuntime(376): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-24 15:21:45.441: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1741)
11-24 15:21:45.441: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at com.icemountaininc.app.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:14)
11-24 15:21:45.441: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
11-24 15:21:45.441: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1424)
11-24 15:21:45.441: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1022)
11-24 15:21:45.441: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
11-24 15:21:45.441: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  ... 11 more
```

Any help please?

Been stuck on this problem for ages!

I use SDK VERSION 8  of android

Thanks.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually You got **NullPointerException** because Your `TextView view` and `Button next` are `NULL`.

**Solution:**

You have to define `TextView view` and `Button next` after `setContentView()` method in `onCreate()` of your Activity.

like:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
final TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
final Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

Comment: Thanks. I will mark you as the anwser because you explained why I got that nullpointer exception!

Comment: In Android all your views are visible after you call `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` then Android prepare Views for your current Activity and you can access reference of these views.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
final TextView view;
final Button next;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            view.setText("These questions will help me to help you :)");
        }
    });
```

In your code

```
final TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
final Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

is called before

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

thats why the views do not get resolved

Answer (score 0):

You are getting Null pointer exception because you are finding the buttons and textViews before setContentView(). Before knowing the layout the buttons and textViews can't be identified. Your code should be like-

@Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

```
  final TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
   final Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
   next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
 {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        view.setText("These questions will help me to help you :)");


    }
});
```

And one more suggestion is don't use the final modifier for the UI controls. If you have a situation wherein you have to update the view on each button click then the final variables will not get modified on each button click instance.